# MaraDNS - location of zone configuration file

Tags: debian, bind, domain-name-system

Does anyone use MaraDNS instead of BIND9? I've installed 1.4.2 on my VPS (Debian 7 x32) in OVH.fr and looked through the documentation. As I conclude, *mararc* configuration file should be located in the */etc* directory. However, I've found that file in */etc/maradns* - it contains a sample configuration, but the entries are not commented out, and it seems that the server uses it (*traceroute* reached the server).

My question is: What should I do? Create */etc/mararc* and remove */etc/maradns/mararc*, put the first one in the place of the second one, or something else?
I will be grateful for lightening the situation.

Yours sincerely,
P.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically the location of configuration files (and binaries and everything really) is a compile time option allowing the administrator to override defaults, or to set new defaults if you like.

I wouldn't be surprised if the Debian package maintainer opted to set up a directory `/etc/maradns` as suggested in the [Debian Policy Manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#s10.7.2).

You place the configuration either at the compiled in default location, or you provide an alternate location with the `-f` switch in your start-up scripts:

```
 maradns -f mararc_file_location
```

It really is your own preference which you use.

Comment: Thanks HBruijin! Anyway, I've asked the author and he said that version from official repos is broken. It's suggested to use own-compiled package.